# How to access the values of an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, tags

I have the code

```
def showTags(post)
    tagString = ''
    tagString += "Politics " if post.tags(:politics)
    tagString += "Technology " if post.tags(:technology)
    tagString += "Entertainment " if post.tags(:entertainment)
    tagString += "Sports " if post.tags(:sports)
    tagString += "Science " if post.tags(:science)
    tagString += "Crime " if post.tags(:crime)
    tagString += "Business " if post.tags(:business)
    tagString += "Social " if post.tags(:social)
    tagString += "Nature " if post.tags(:nature)
    tagString += "Other " if post.tags(:other)

    return tagString
end
```

My tags model has 10 boolean values (politics, tech, etc...) and `belongs_to :post`. When you make a new post there are check boxes that correspond to each field. So after making a post there are some trues and some false values. The problem arises when I call this method in the post#index, in order to display which tags belong to this post. The problem is that all of the words display, i played with the console and the post.tags is correct (some true and some false values) however `if post.tags(:politics)` (or whatever) always returns true. I tried using `if post.tags.politics` but that just gave an error.

Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `belongs_to :post` in your `Tag` class and `has_many :tags` in your `Post` class then the `tags` attribute is a list so you either need to iterate over it:

```
post.tags.each {|tag| puts tag.politics}
```

Or index into it:

```
post.tags[0].politics
```

From an outside glance this type of model doesn't make too much sense though. Maybe do `has_one :tag` in the `Post` class instead. Then you can call `post.tag.politics`.

Comment: Hmm, i get this error **can't convert Symbol into Integer** when I switch them to square brackets

Comment: I updated the answer, but I had to make assumptions since your model is not clear.

Comment: Thank you, but i think that using the gem act-as-taggable-on is the way to go. Or maybe just putting all of the boolean values in the posts table instead of using a separate table